# Determine limit of $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_n + A/x_n)$ $A$ and $n$ are positive

Tags: real-analysis

If $x$ and $A$ are positive and $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}(x + A/x)$,$x_2 = \frac{1}{2}(x_1 + A/x_1)$, and
so forth, prove that the sequence $x_n$  is convergent and determine its limit.

My attempt:

Proving the convergence was easy enough, I showed that since $x_n = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1} + A/x_{n-1}) \geq \sqrt{A}$ using the geometric-arithmetic inequality that $x_n$ is bounded below.

Then, I did $x_{n+1}-x_{n}=\frac{1}{2}(A/x_{n}-x_n) \leq 0 $ using the fact that $x_n \geq \sqrt{A} \space for \space all\space  n$

Which implies that $x_n$ is monotone decreasing. So we can conclude that it is convergent.

However, I am having trouble proving what the limit is even though I know that it is $\sqrt{A}$. I can't seem to get a tight upper bound no matter what I try.

I am stuck at :

$\sqrt{A} \leq x_n \leq x_1$

Any help as to how I can get a better upper bound to trap $x_n$ would really be appreciated. Aslo if you have any comment on what I wrote or if you want to add anything please do:)

Thank you!!

Comment: Duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/509407) known as the "Babylonian method".

Answer (score 1):

**hint** assume $\lim x_n =a=\lim x_{n+1}$ and subs back in the eq. And solve for $a$.